# Card.io not allowing to scan credit card

Tags: android, card.io

I am using card.io android sdk to integrate credit card payment functionality but it's not allowing me to scan card information it simply tells to enter card information and then do nothing.

The below is my code

package org.my.scanExample;

```
import io.card.payment.CardIOActivity;
import io.card.payment.CreditCard;
import org.my.scanExample.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyScanActivity extends Activity
{
    // You MUST register with card.io to get an app token. Go to https://card.io/apps/new/
    private static final String MY_CARDIO_APP_TOKEN = "App_Token";

    final String TAG = getClass().getName();

    private Button scanButton;
    private TextView resultTextView;

    private int MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE = 100; // arbitrary int

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        resultTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
        scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        resultTextView.setText("card.io library version: " + CardIOActivity.sdkVersion() + "\nBuilt: " + CardIOActivity.sdkBuildDate());

        if (CardIOActivity.canReadCardWithCamera(this)) {
            scanButton.setText("Scan a credit card with card.io");
        }
        else {
            scanButton.setText("Enter credit card information");
        }
    }

    public void onScanPress(View v) {
        // This method is set up as an onClick handler in the layout xml
        // e.g. android:onClick="onScanPress"

        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, CardIOActivity.class);

        // required for authentication with card.io
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_APP_TOKEN, MY_CARDIO_APP_TOKEN);

        // customize these values to suit your needs.
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: true
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_ZIP, false); // default: false

        // hides the manual entry button
        // if set, developers should provide their own manual entry mechanism in the app
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, false); // default: false

        // MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE is arbitrary and is only used within this activity.
        startActivityForResult(scanIntent, MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String resultStr;
        if (data != null && data.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT)) {
            CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);

            // Never log a raw card number. Avoid displaying it, but if necessary use getFormattedCardNumber()
            resultStr = "Card Number: " + scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber() + "\n";

            // Do something with the raw number, e.g.:
            // myService.setCardNumber( scanResult.cardNumber );

            if (scanResult.isExpiryValid()) {
                resultStr += "Expiration Date: " + scanResult.expiryMonth + "/" + scanResult.expiryYear + "\n"; 
            }

            if (scanResult.cvv != null) { 
                // Never log or display a CVV
                resultStr += "CVV has " + scanResult.cvv.length() + " digits.\n";
            }

            if (scanResult.zip != null) {
                resultStr += "Zip: " + scanResult.zip + "\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            resultStr = "Scan was canceled.";
        }
        resultTextView.setText(resultStr);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any hint in the logcat? (I assume that you've replaced  "My App Token" with the one you got from https://www.card.io/accounts/register/developer in your real code?)

Comment: No i am not getting any exception in logcat.I have put my generated app token in my application. One more question is that is it free api or it charge for using of sdk.

Comment: Could you paste in the logcat? There may be some other messages that provide a clue, even if no exceptions are logged.

Comment: And, BTW, the published price is $0.15/scan. See https://www.card.io/how-it-works/

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know the device model you are testing on.

Comment: Hi The log error is here:
Failed to load native library:couldn't load CardioDecider IndLibrary
return null

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String MY_CARDIO_APP_TOKEN = "App_Token";
```

your app token is not valid. use the valid token